# @ReactProp setter doesn't called

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have tried to implement gradient view via native UI component RN approach (Android only for now). Everything seems fine except one: `@ReactProp` setters doesn't called and I don't even imagine why :(

**Details**:

```
- RN version: 0.60.4
```

Here is the code (ViewManager, View, RN component):

**ViewManager**:

```
package com.bastionpassmobile.splashgradient;

import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;

/**
 * View manager for splash background gradient view.
 */
public class SplashGradientViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<SplashGradientView> {
    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "RCTSplashGradientView";

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    protected SplashGradientView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new SplashGradientView(reactContext);
    }
}
```

**View**:

```
package com.bastionpassmobile.splashgradient;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RadialGradient;
import android.graphics.Shader;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp;
import com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup;

/**
 * View serves as background gradient for splash screen.
 */
public class SplashGradientView extends ReactViewGroup {
    float radius;
    int[] colors;
    int width;
    int height;

    public SplashGradientView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        radius = 0;
        colors = new int[0];
        width = 0;
        height = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (radius > 0) {
            RadialGradient radialGradient = new RadialGradient(width / 2, height / 2, radius, colors, null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setShader(radialGradient);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    /**
     * Sets gradient radius.
     * @param {SplashGradientView} view
     * @param {float} value
     */
    @ReactProp(name = "radius")
    public void setRadius(SplashGradientView view, float value) {
        radius = value;
        view.invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Sets gradient colors.
     * @param {SplashGradientView} view
     * @param {ReadableArray} value
     */
    @ReactProp(name = "colors")
    public void setColors(SplashGradientView view, ReadableArray value) {
        colors = new int[value.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < value.size(); i++) {
            colors[i] = Color.parseColor(value.getString(i));
        }
        view.invalidate();
    }
}
```

**RN component**:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { requireNativeComponent, StyleProp, ViewStyle } from "react-native";

interface CRadialGradientProps {
    style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
    radius: number;
    /**
     * Each element of the array should be defined as hex color representation.
     */
    colors: string[];
}

const RadialGradientView = requireNativeComponent("RCTSplashGradientView");

/**
 * Represents radial gradient view.
 */
export class CRadialGradient extends React.Component<CRadialGradientProps> {
    render() {
        return (
            <RadialGradientView {...this.props}/>
        );
    }
}
```

**And render of course**:

```
render() {
    <CRadialGradient
        radius={600}
        colors={["#353946", "#1E212C"]}
    />    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's my mistake :) `@ReactProp` setters should be placed in `ViewManager` implementation instead of `View`. When I moved methods from `View` to `ViewManager`, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now looking at [the docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android#3-expose-view-property-setters-using-reactprop-or-reactpropgroup-annotation), but they could be more explicit on this point